# Envrypt sql_alchemy_conn in airflow config file (ansible)

Tags: encryption, ansible, airflow

Is there a way to encrypt the airflow config file sql_alchemy_conn string , the password shown in example is plaintext . What options are there to secure it. Also if the password has special chars how it must be escaped in the config file

Trying to install airflow using airflow role.

# See: https://www.sqlalchemy.org/
  sql_alchemy_conn:
     value: "postgresql+psycopg2://pgclusteradm@servername:PLAINTEXTPASSWORD@server.postgres.database.azure.com/airflow2"

Way to encrypt password, couldn't find how to encrypt this.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the database URI through environment variables instead of the config file. This doesn't encrypt it or necessarily make it more secure, but it at least isn't plainly sitting in a permanent file.

In your `airflow.cfg` you can put a placeholder:

```
[core]
...
sql_alchemy_conn = override_me
...
```

Then set `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=postgresql+psycopg2://...` in an environment variable when you bring up Airflow components. This way of setting and overriding configuration options through environment variables is detailed in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/set-config.html), but the basic format is `AIRFLOW__{SECTION}__{KEY}=<value>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of securing this as mentioned in [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/set-config.html):

1) **Environment Variable**:

You can override the setting in `airflow.cfg` by setting the following environment variable:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN=my_conn_string
```

This way you can keep the setting in `airflow.cfg` as empty so no one can view the password.

2) **Get string by running command**:

You can also derive the connection string at run time by appending `_cmd` to the key like this:

```
[core]
sql_alchemy_conn_cmd = bash_command_to_run
```

Comment: and how to escape special characters?